# Provide a Proof for the following statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f : X\longrightarrow Y$ be any function. Show that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$ for any
$B\subseteq Y$.

I understand the logic behind this statement, but I'm unsure about how someone would prove this.

Answer (score 2):

If $y\in f(f^{-1}(B))$ then there is $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $x\in f^{-1}(B)$, we have $f(x)\in B$ and so $y=f(x)\in B$.